# RODBC - Set maximum query time for sqlQuery()

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I'm using the RODBC-package in R to query an SQL-server database. Is there a way to set a maximum query time using this package, i.e. the sqlQuery-function returns  an error if the query runs for more than 30 minutes?

Comment: You can't do that with RODBC, but **RODBCext** has this feature. Another way is to use `withTimeout` from package R.utils.